# How do I convert dates from "Month DD,YY" to "MM/DD/YY" in python?

Tags: python, datetime

How do I convert April 28,2015 to 04/28/15 in python?
I can assign April = 4 but not April 04. How do I do that?

Comment: Please keep it to **one** question per post.

Comment: ok sorry! but that question is on hold

Comment: What kind of object is your `April 28,2015` value, a string?

Comment: That doesn't mean you can just add it to another question. Read the reasons why it is on hold and *improve the question*, so that it can be re-opened.

Comment: In the previous post someone recommended me to look for slicing which I did and I am able to truncated the last name to 10 characters but still having trouble how to add hyphen if the name is too short

Comment: I added the improvement but seems like no one is answering it

Comment: So I want to give a try on new question

Comment: April 28,2015 is a string

Comment: I've already removed that portion from your post. What remains is not enough of a question either; maybe you want to read up on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, including the linked articles at the bottom.

Comment: Is there are any way I can pm you the code and have you look at my code?

Answer (score 4):

```
C:> pip install python-dateutil
C:> python
...
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> print "STACK OVERFLOW SAVED MY BACON ON:",parse("April 28,2015").strftime("%m/%d/%y")
```

If you are sure of the format, you could of course specify exactly:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> print datetime.datetime.strptime("%B %d,%Y","April 28,2015").strftime("%m/%d/%y")
```

Comment: Thanks you replying, I don't quite understand how your answer work. I am a beginner programmer that just start programming in college for couple weeks. I haven't learn those stuff yet. Can you maybe give me some suggestion in a novice way?

Comment: this is the most basic way ... you have dateutil parse the string into a date ... then you tell the date how you want it formatted

Comment: I was thinking about maybe assign January = 01... December = 12 for the months. Then for the day I just called input and the year I just do input()[2:4].  Is that a good idea? Seems like python doesn't allow January = 01 but rather it allows January = 1. In the program I have to write the exact output.

Comment: sure `{"January":"01",...,"April":"04"}` but yeah that is not a good idea ... unfortunately if this is homework assignment my solution likely is not what the teacher excpects ... but this is how you solve this problem

Comment: For the name that need to use hyphen I have no idea of how to do it? I was thinking maybe doing something like %10s.

Comment: @JoranBeasley  `dateutil` looks amazing, can you provide the API link here?

Comment: But it doesn't give extra hyphen when you input a name like John. I guess it only appears as "John" rather than "John------". I only give you the first ten character of your string.

Comment: name[:10] + "-"*max(0,10-len(name))

Comment: @haifzhan ... tbh all I have ever used is parser.parse ... and its always worked awesomely....

Comment: Probably simpler to use `name[:10].ljust(10, '-')`.

Comment: yeah thats the command i was trying to remember i just didnt care enough to try very hard :P

Comment: Is there are anyway to change the date besides using datetime module? I emailed the professor and he said its not recommended for solving this problem but normally would if you were writing a serious application.

Comment: I am talking about any date not just April 28,2015. Like how do I turn Months Day, Year into some like MM/DD/YY.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I have taken care of the hyphen problem and the truncated problem. I just need to turn any Months Day, Year  to MM/DD/YY

Answer (score 2):

The standard module datetime includes this functionality.  The below code sets a string to the date in question.  I then create a date/time object from the string using `strptime`.  I then output the date from the object in the requested format.

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = 'April 28, 2015'

dtObject = datetime.strptime(dt,"%B %d, %Y")

dtConverted = dtObject.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes both the input and desired output are text:

```
import datetime 

>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('April 28, 2015', '%B %d, %Y').strftime('%m/%d/%y')
'04/28/15'
```

The other formats are [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).